# Why codepush can't update native code in react-native apps?

Tags: code-push, react-native-code-push

Why [codepush](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push) can't update native code in react-native apps?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons, but one of the biggest reasons why is Apple's publishing guidelines for App Store apps. They explicitly do not allow updating native code on client devices once they have been installed from their store. Enabling native code updates would lead to submissions being rejected en masse.